# Can Magento 2 handle complex price calculations?

Tags: magento2, price

I have products with around 10-20 attributes(in the form of dropdown-fields) and 2-20 options per attribute. The price has to change depending on what options are selected.

So it is not possible for me to use "configurable products" and create every single combination of options.

Is their a way to add a complex price calculation to my products?

Comment: Of course you can do by custom module you can use event for final price to set piece for your calculation.

Comment: i can´t use just events, i actually need the price to get calculated dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Magento 2.0 isn't very good with creating huge configurable products where you want to options to change with your selection on the product page. It tries to exponentially create products which can create thousands of unused or even impossible combinations of options that you have to manually disable.  We have had the same issue with large option fields for our products we would like to have that generate specific part numbers. But I'd try to avoid this as much as possible because of the time it takes to find a solution. Best bet is to go the custom (smart) options route...but even now Magento is having issues with the current extensions and forgetting price data.

Comment: I can´t make my price calculations with the custom options, it is not maintainable, i guess i have to use a few tricks and some Ajax-calls that fire. That way I could use my own price calculations or draw the numbers from a .csv file.